# Duplicate a row in SQL?

Tags: sql

OK I have a table that has two columns, userID and courseID. It is used to assign training courses to a user. It looks like this:

```
userid   courseid
0          1
0          3
0          6
1          1
1          4
1          5
```

so user 0 is assigned to courses 1,3,6 and user 1 is assigned to 1, 4 5

anyways I need to take every user that is assigned to 6 and create a new row that has that userid and courseid 11, basically assigning every user who is currently assigned to 6 to also be assigned to 11

for some reason (I did not create this database) both rows are marked as primary keys, and some statements I have tried have thrown an error because of this, what the heck is the deal?

oh maybe it is because there are a few users that are already assigned to 11 so it is choking on those maybe?

please help

Comment: Both "columns" are marked as primary keys, you mean. Not "rows".

Answer (score 69, accepted):

```
Insert Into TableName (userID, courseID)
  Select userID, 11 From TableName Where courseID=6;
```

Also, I'm a bit confused by your comment that both are primary keys.  Both rows can be *part* of the primary key or both can be Unique keys but they cannot both be a primary key.  As far as errors go, it is probably because the query tried to insert rows that were duplicates of already existing rows.  To eliminate this possibility you could do this:

```
Insert Into TableName (userID, courseID)
  Select userID, 11 From TableName Where courseID=6 
     AND (userID not in (Select userID From TableName Where courseID=11))
```

Depending on your database this could work too:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO TableName (userID, courseID)
    SELECT userID, 11 FROM TableName WHERE courseID=6;
```

Anyway, there you go.

Comment: GS - that is an interesting construct - where does it work?  It doesn't work in SQL Server 2005...

Comment: I couln't get `insert or ignore` to work in PostgreSQL, works in sqlite3, though.

Comment: `insert or ignore` does not seem to work in MySQL either.

Answer (score 2):

```
insert into TableName (userId, courseId)
    select userId, 11
    from   TableName
    where  courseId = 6
    and    not exists (
               select 1
               from   TableName nested
               where  nested.userId = TableName.UserId
               and    nested.courseId = 11
           )
```

Selects all users that are assigned to courseId 6 but are not yet assigned to courseId 11 and inserts a new record into the table for them for courseId 11.

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
INSERT
INTO   [table]
       (
              userid,
              courseid
       )
SELECT userid,
       11
FROM   [table]
WHERE  courseid    = 6
   AND userid NOT IN
                     (SELECT userid
                     FROM    [table]
                     WHERE   courseid = 11
                     );
```

This will select all users in course 6 not in course 11 and add them with course 11 to the table.

Comment: Ummm....this won't work.  A record with a courseID of 6 will, by definition, not also have a courseID of 11.  You need a subQuery as I show in my answer.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that as soon as I posted and rewrote it.  But then I was beaten to the punch.

Comment: Ok - I'm taking off my downvote then.  I just didn't want to confuse Ryan so I felt like I had to downvote it.  But, truly, I *hate* downvoting answers on a thread that I've supplied an answer to.  So, I'm happy to take it off!

Comment: Often, it's better to delete the answer and add a new one, because people that find this question won't understand why it has been downvoted.

Comment: I can give this an upvote to negate some of the confusion.